# how to evaluate input data in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, evaluate

Hello I have a problem with evaluating input data, firstly I scan an integer value like this:

```
scanf("%d", &vstup2)
```

and then I state a condition whether it's equal to zero as follows:

```
if (vstup2 == 0){
        printf ("Nedefinovany vysledek!\n");
```

but when I input zero to this variable, it doesn't output printf statement but instead this line of code:

```
Floating point exception: 8
```

Here is the entire code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int vstup1;
    int vstup2 = 0;
    int sucet = 0;
    int rozdil = 0;
    int soucin = 0;
    int podil = 0;

    float prumer = 0;

    printf("INPUT FIRST INTEGER\n");

    if (scanf("%d", &vstup1)&& (vstup1 < -10000 || vstup1 > 10000)) 
    {
        printf("WRONG INPUT\n");
        return 0;
    }


    printf("INPUT SECOND INTEGER\n");
    scanf("%d", &vstup2); 

    if (vstup2 <= -10000 || vstup2 >= 10000)    
    {
        printf("WRONG INPUT\n");
        return 0;
    }

    sucet = (vstup1 + vstup2);
    rozdil = (vstup1 - vstup2);
    soucin = (vstup1 * vstup2);
    podil =  (vstup1 / vstup2);
    prumer = ((vstup1 + vstup2)/2);

    printf("Desitkova soustava: %i  %i\n", vstup1, vstup2);
    printf("Sestnactkova soustava: %x %x\n", vstup1, vstup2);  
    printf("Soucet: %i + %i = %i\n",vstup1, vstup2, sucet);
    printf("Rozdil: %i - %i = %i\n",vstup1, vstup2, rozdil);
    printf("Soucin: %i * %i = %i\n",vstup1, vstup2, soucin);
    if (vstup2 != 0)
    {
        printf("Podil: %i / %i = %i\n",vstup1, vstup2, podil);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Nedefinovany vysledek!\n");
    }
    printf("Prumer: %0.1f \n",prumer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Divide by zero `podil =  (vstup1 / vstup2);`. You got to move your `if (vstup2 != 0){ to`  top.

Answer (score 0):

You have a division by `0`, that's the error you have. You have to protect against it.

Answer (score 0):

You have got to handle the `Floating point exception (core dumped)` when the user gives `vstup2=0`.
Just add

```
if(vstup2==0)
{
 //print some exception 
return 0;
}
```